# Git subdirectories replicated in many repositories

Tags: git

For my thesis, I have a Git repository `repo_0` which contains a number of subdirectories. Something like:

```
thesis/
    .git/
    data/
    experiments/
    papers/
    algorithm_1/
    algorithm_2/
```

I'm the only person with access to the repository. However, I would like to share `algorithm_1` and `algorithm2` with more people so that they can eventually contribute.

How can I link `algorithm_1/` and `algorithm_2/` to their own repositories `repo_1` and `repo_2` while keeping them also in `repo_0`?

A naive solution would be to get the algorithms out of `repo0` and maintain three repositories, but I'm looking for a lazier solution where:

- If I commit in `repo_0`, changes in `algorithm_n` propagate to `repo_n` and `repo_2`
- If I commit in `repo_1`, changes propagate to `repo_0`

What would do suggest as the closest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime example where [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are great. You treat each repository as their own repo (maintain three repos) but have essentially "soft links" to a specific commit in your repo_0 to your other repos. This works as if the submodules are remote repositories but you keep the local copy with your repo_0.

Check out this [great tutorial](http://www.speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a submodule.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule